# Who are the "Darksiders" in the eponymous game?

Tags: darksiders

The wikipedia page does not make any mention of them. I'm playing it and haven't yet heard any mention of who they are.

Comment: I've been under the impression that "Darksiders" simply is used as another name for the four horsemen of the apocalypse. Could be wrong though, I don't really have a source for it.

Comment: The "Darksiders" logo has a devil tail, which imply some affiliation with Hell... but the horsemen are not from Hell!

Comment: Videogames have been known to take some liberty with the source material: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial_%28video_game%29

Comment: Even ingame the Horsemen are not affiliated with Hell.

Comment: Good question... strange that the very title of the game should fail to be linked to anything meaningful.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the sub-titles of the games, Darksiders seem to be the horsemen themselves and the game is the telling of each darksider's, aka horsemen's, tale. The original game's full title is **Darksiders: Wrath of War** as described by the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darksiders). The second game is known as **Darksiders II: Death Lives** as described by the [trailer video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=CExRGMDAvTY). It also fits the description of the horsemen race of Nephilim as stated by the [wikia.](http://darksiders.wikia.com/wiki/Nephilim)

> Nephilim are an ancient and endangered race older than both Angels or Demons (they are Old Ones along with the Charred Council etc) made by The Creator to be protectors of Mankind who fought against the Darkness with great ferocity. But the primitive Nephilim, flawed and corruptible, were finally exiled from the Light.

I interpret their name to describe their exile from the Light.